# ¿Como modificar estilos en archivo excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Quiero abrir un archivo .xlsx y modificarlo con Python y openpyxl
quiero cambiarle el tipo de letra, etc. El problema que me da un error y no he podido solucionarlo este es el error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, Fill
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/angel.torreso/Documents/Prueba2.xlsx')

ws = wb.active

_cell = ws.cell('A1')


_cell.style.font.color.index = Color.GREEN
_cell.style.font.name = 'Arial'
_cell.style.font.size = 8
_cell.style.font.bold = True
_cell.style.alignment.wrap_text = True


_cell.style.fill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID
_cell.style.fill.start_color.index = Color.DARKRED


wb.save("C:/Users/angel.torreso/Documents/Prueba2.xlsx")

class Color(HashableObject):
"""Named colors for use in styles."""
   BLACK = 'FF000000'
   WHITE = 'FFFFFFFF'
   RED = 'FFFF0000'
   DARKRED = 'FF800000'
   BLUE = 'FF0000FF'
   DARKBLUE = 'FF000080'
   GREEN = 'FF00FF00'
   DARKGREEN = 'FF008000'
   YELLOW = 'FFFFFF00'
   DARKYELLOW = 'FF808000'
```

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tu código no es correcto para versiones recientes de openpyxl. Han cambiado bastantes cosas, por ejemplo, ahora los estilos son inmutables (desde versión 1.9).

El error en si se debe a que el método `cell` espera recibir dos argumentos indicando la fila y columna, por ejemplo `cell = sheet.cell(row=2, column=4)`. Si quieres acceder usando la nomenclatura de Excel simplemente debes hacer `cell = sheet["A1"]`.

Dicho esto, puedes hacer lo que deseas de la siguiente forma:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, fills, Alignment, PatternFill, NamedStyle


wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/angel.torreso/Documents/Prueba2.xlsx')
ws = wb.active


font = Font(name='Arial',
            size=8,
            bold=True,
            color=colors.GREEN)

fill = PatternFill(fill_type=fills.FILL_SOLID,
                   start_color=colors.DARKRED)
alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)

cell = ws['A1']

cell.font += font
cell.fill += fill
cell.alignment += alignment

wb.save('C:/Users/angel.torreso/Documents/Prueba2.xlsx')
```

Puedes ver más ejemplos sobre como trabajar con los estilos en la documentación oficial (en inglés): [Working with styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)